# ant 1.8 vs. 1.9 and excludes

Tags: java, ant

I have the following in my ant file:

```
<javac compiler="modern" srcdir="${dir.src}" destdir="${dir.build}">
        <excludes name="Foo.java"/>
        <excludes name="Bar.java"/>
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

This works fine with ant 1.9.6

Though the ant parser of IntelliJ and ant 1.8 don't like this syntax and try to compile the excluded files.

How can I rewrite this portable?

Answer (score 0):

It's `<exclude>` without an `"s"`:

```
<javac compiler="modern" srcdir="${dir.src}" destdir="${dir.build}">
    <exclude name="Foo.java"/>
    <exclude name="Bar.java"/>
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

`<exclude>` works in all versions of Ant.

Comment: no exclude (without s) is accepted by intellij but it does not work with neither 1.8 nor 1.9.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get errors? Update your question and show the exact output of Ant. I just ran Ant with a `<javac>` with an `<exclude>` under it and the excluded file is not compiled.

Comment: It tries to compile the excluded classes. The output is not really useful.

Comment: The output is useful because it should contain lines like `[javac] Compiling 1 source file to ...`. Please add the output to your question.

Comment: Indeed it says compiling 59 files, while there are 61, still the error messages popup

Comment: Could it be that ant is too intelligent and ignores the exclude if the Class is still referenced from other classes?